# Modify date format on x axis in R?

Tags: r, date, graphics, plot

I want to change the format of my plot in R in month year.

So currently it is displaying the day too, I want to have only month year.

With my [data](http://uploadeasy.net/upload/6nhi.rar) and the R code:

```
plot(alvdate[1250:1600],c(NA,alvlloss)[1250:1600],type="l",lwd=1,main="",xlab="",ylab="log loss",cex.axis=1.2,cex.lab=1.2,xaxt="n")
axis.Date(1, at = seq(alvdate[1250], alvdate[1600], length.out=20),
        labels = seq(alvdate[1250], alvdate[1600], length.out=20),
        format= "%m/%y", las = 2)
```

I get the picture

[image]

I get the format yyyy-mm-dd but I want to have yyyy-mm so e.g.

```
2008-01
2008-02
```

and so on. I alredy set the format to "%m/%y" but this does not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `format= "%Y-%m"`, to write something like this :

```
axis.Date(1, at = seq(alvdate[1250], alvdate[1600], length.out=20),
        format= "%Y-%m", las = 2)
```

Comment: thanks, I will accept your answer, but can you tell me one thing: The value on 2008-08 is not the first day of the month it is the 18th? the value before is the 28 July 2008, I used stock prices to calculate the returns. There are no stock prices in this period between 28 July 2008 until 18 Aug 2008. Why? This is Allianz Xetra.

Comment: Sorry  don't get your question. Does your question why there is not a quotation for the stock Allianz Xetra, from 28 July 2008 until 18 Aug 2008?

Comment: yeah! I just downloaded it from yahoo finance and saw this. This is visible in my plot.

Comment: @StatTistician hard to say anything without a context? do you use `quantmod`? which quotation name are you using (^XXX)? I can't find Allianz Xetra.

Comment: I go to http://de.finance.yahoo.com/ and go for Allianz SE (ALV.DE)
-XETRA Ticker: 840400/ISIN: DE0008404005 then I click on historical prices and search for the values in this time period. and I get the output:


18. Aug 2008    109,22  110,87  108,29  109,50  1.691.000   93,29

28. Jul 2008    108,49  108,49  106,09  107,00  2.508.000   91,16

Comment: @StatTistician I don't know why yahoo don't have quotation during this period. You can try another source , google for example.